# Inserting items into list at correct index

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Currently creating a reorder function that inserts elements from one list into an empty list, and subsequent items are placed at particular indices based on the comparison of that element in the `from_list` to the `to_list`. So for an original list of `from_list = [4, 5, 6, 3, 9, 88, 2]`, the ideal output would be `to_list = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 88]`. Here's the code I have:

```
def reorder(to_list, from_list):

    for i in range(len(from_list)):
        if not to_list:
            to_list.insert(0, from_list[i])
        elif from_list[i] < to_list[i - 1] and i == 1:
            to_list.insert(0 , from_list[i])
        elif from_list[i] < to_list[i - 1] and i > 1:
            to_list.insert(to_list[i - 2], from_list[i])
        elif from_list[i] >= to_list[i - 1]:
            to_list.append(from_list[i])

    return to_list
```

I've spent quite some time trying to place the indices properly, but the elements are not being inserted in the right order. For a list of `[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]` it goes `[9], [8,9]` but then 7 is supposed to be inserted before 9 when `i = 2` and hence my intention was for it to be inserted at position 0. But instead it's appended to the end of the list, resulting in `[8, 9, 7]`.

I know there are specific re-order functions in Python, and there's more efficient ways to re-order an existing list, but for the sake of this function my aim is to read items one at a time and append them to an initially empty list.

So for an initial list of `[2, 6, 4, 4, 7]`, the insertion order would go `[2], [2, 6], [2, 4, 6], [2, 4, 4, 6], [2, 4, 4, 6, 7]`.

Comment: You make at most 3 comparisons between the value to insert & items in `to_list`.  That is not necessarily enough to determine where it should go.

Comment: You need two nested loops to implement insertion sort.

Answer (score 2):

There is a built-in function which will insert an item into the correct place in an already sorted list and will do it efficiently - [`bisect.insort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.insort).

```
>>> import bisect
>>> data = [2, 5, 11, 45, 67]
>>> bisect.insort(data, 7)
>>> data
[2, 5, 7, 11, 45, 67]
```

Comment: Well, sort of efficiently.  It finds the location in O(log n), but then the insertion is still O(n).

Comment: The idea is to not use any built-in sorting function. Could a while loop in one of the if blocks do the trick?

Comment: Using a while loop nested within the first elif did the trick! `while to_list[0] > to_list[1] and i > 0: to_list[0], to_list[1] = to_list[1], to_list[0]`

Comment: @FrankYellin Yes, well, as efficiently as possible given that it is a list.

Comment: @JimT Yes, that works well for a homework assignment, where you are supposed to learn something. In real life, you solution is much slower than the already slow enough built-in solution ;)